# geodatabase with multiple projection

Tags: arcgis-10.0, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, .net, file-geodatabase

I have a geodatabase (ESRI/PostgreSQL) I'm working in an application for digitizing : 
in my country we have 4 coordinate system(projection), so I'm looking for a way to switch projection or any other idea or set projection parameter to all my feature classes.

Comment: i want the application to be able to work in the 4 zone (4 coordinate system with the same database )

Comment: Do you need to store your data separately for each coordinate system? If so, you should consider just using a separate feature data set for each coordinate system. If you would like to store all of the data in one feature class, i would suggest researching a unifying coordinate system which encompasses your entire country.  Unless there is a regulatory/statute reason to maintain 4 coordinate systems, I would further suggest you create your own custom projection.

Comment: thank you @Clickinaway, so please can i  create a custom projection that include the 4 coordinates system ?

Answer (score 2):

Mounaim, If you are after a custom projection, this [knowledge base article](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/30583) at ESRI is a good place to start, particularly with the links at the bottom. So to be clear, yes, you can create a custom projection and based on what you've provided, I think you will be much better off storing your data in one projection with one caveat: I'm not sure how large your country is or how accurate your data needs to be, [distortion](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/natureofgeoinfo/c2_p29.html) is always something to be highly aware of.

There are a multitude of factors to consider when designing this, for us, *area* was our most important concern over our regional management, such that we created several regionally based projections over the USA.

If you have maintenance that is up to date with ESRI, I'd suggest you try to track down Margaret Maher, she's the guru, but I'm not sure if she works in tech support anymore, but if you can get a hold of her, you'll be in good shape.